# How can I controle the visibility level of a div and make it see through?

Tags: css, html, visibility

Can I control the visibility of some *div* in my website and make to become see-through using CSS only? In flash it's done through controlling what is called *Alfa* so I'm wondering if such a thing exist in CSS!

**Edition 001**

Can I control the opacity of the *div*'s background only? So the text in the div wouldn't be effected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html

```
.opaque1 {  // for all other browsers
    opacity: .5;
}

.opaque2 {  // for IE5-7
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.opaque3 {  // for IE8
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
}
```

Comment: Can I control the opacity of the background only? So the text in the div wouldn't be effected?

Comment: In decent browsers, as `nikc` said, you can use rgba colors: `background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5) //transulcent red`.  But again, IE will barf on this.

This page has a snippet of another filter hack that will work in IE though: http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

But really you may have better luck with a semi transparent PNG image set to the color and opacity you want.

Comment: transparent PNG! Very interesting trick!
Would it work with all browsers?

Comment: @MAK - in all but IE6 (at least, not without a hack - see DDBelatedPNG)

Answer (score 3):

You can use opacity in CSS

```
.transparent_class {
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

I think there are some problems with opacity in Internet Explorer so here is example how to change transparency in IE:

```
.opaque1 { // for all other browsers
 opacity: .5;
}

.opaque2 { // for IE5-7
 filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.opaque3 { // for IE8
 -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
}
```

HTH

Comment: Yes, but IE6, and perhaps 7, will barf on this.  In those browsers, you don't set opacity without some javascript library or filter hack.

Comment: This is one way, but it has the downside that all descendants inherit the same opacity. If you only want the background-color to be see-through, you can use `background-color: rgba(12, 34, 56, 0.5)` where the last number is the alpha channels value (0-1).

Comment: Will this
>>background-color: rgba(12, 34, 56, 0.5)<< 
be supported in all browsers?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to make only the background transparent is by using a transparent png as background-image, and then use [this jQuery fix](https://web.archive.org/web/20130128041818/http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/) for the special snowflake IE. This works in all browsers as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good link talking about CSS navigation menue I hope it would be helpful:

http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/css-navigation-menu.shtml